# Cannot solve MissingKeyMapError on ng-map

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I'm aware that there are already a few questions concerning this topic but none of the answers provided solved the problem. And after searching half the internet I'm desperate for help.

The map starts to load for half a second then shows the grey eror screen and in the console I get the MissingKeyMapError from google.

I use the following code in my html:

```
<div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" 
     map-lazy-load-params="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_HARDCODED_KEY">
        <ng-map class="map" 
                center="{{main.map.center.latitude}},{{main.map.center.longitude}}" 
                zoom="{{main.map.zoom}}" 
                map-Type-Control="false" 
                map-type-id="TERRAIN" 
                street-view-control="false">
        </ng-map>
</div>
```

I even hardcoded the key to eliminate possible points of failure. As far as I can see this is the exact same thing as in the docs at https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps. I am not using an aditional script tag anywhere in the project. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thankful for any help

EDIT:

It works when testing in on my local machine (windows 10) with gulp serve. But when I deploy (build with gulp) on the server (ubuntu 14.04 LTS) I get the MissingKeyMapError

Comment: Guess your api key have been setted to be used at specific IP, You may have to check your developer console.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, including working on localhost but not on a server. In my case it works when the page is refreshed.